# I need to get number of days from between two dates

Tags: date, meteor

I need to get  number of days from between two dates.
For example

> 2015.08.10 12:00 - 2015-08-12 12:00 result:2 days
>   i need take the result like that i did something but it doesn' work.

```
    Template.RezSistemi.events({
      "click #rezervasyonkaydet": function(event, template){
        var date1_ms = template.$('#iadetarihi').val();
        var date_ms=template.$('#alistarihi').val();
        var formatli =date_ms-date1_ms;
        alert(formatli);


      }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kresten suggested, time handling is difficult without the help of a good library - and that goes for most programming languages. moment.js is a great library for javascript, which does just that. 
Here is what you can do using that:

```
Template.RezSistemi.events({
      "click #rezervasyonkaydet": function(event, template){

        var date1_ms = moment(template.$('#iadetarihi').val(), "YYYY.MM.DD HH:mm");
        var date_ms= moment(template.$('#alistarihi').val(), "YYYY.MM.DD HH:mm");
        var days = moment.duration(date_ms - date1_ms).asDays();
        alert(days + ' days');
      }
});
```

Comment: Ah, yes. We forgot to parse the date strings. Try it now.

Answer (score 0):

Time  handling is *very* hard, use a library!

MomentJS can do it:
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/to/

Falsehoods programmers believe about time:
http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time